# UWP StreamSocket. Why does my http connection fail when https requests work?

Tags: http, uwp

I'm trying to integrate a connection method for http. I found this code for UWP:

```
 StreamSocket clientSocket = new StreamSocket();
        HostName serverHost = new HostName("ecosia.org");
        string serverServiceName = "https";

    // Try to connect to contoso using HTTP (port 80)
    try {
        // Call ConnectAsync method with a plain socket
        await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, serverServiceName, SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);

        NotifyUser("Connected");

    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Connection failed.");
        // If this is an unknown status it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
        if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown) {
            throw;
        }

                    NotifyUser("Connect failed with error: " + exception.Message);//, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        // Could retry the connection, but for this simple example
        // just close the socket.

        clientSocket.Dispose();
        clientSocket = null; 
        return;
    }
```

This works for establishing https connections. However, I need to access a http-page and tried changing the first two lines like this:

```
HostName serverHost = new HostName("www.seite.com");
string serverServiceName = "http";
```

But this fails in UWP. How can I solve this problem? Note that wen I try establishing via HttpClient classes, I'm facing the same issues.

Comment: What's the error info? https and http use different port by default, one is 443 and another one is 80. You can check this first. If that is not the case we may need to check the error info in details.

Comment: Exception triggered. "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll WinRT-Information: A connection failed because of timeout by answering side. Or the connection failed because the connected host didn't answer.    By the way, I managed connection with httpClient in the meantime to a http-Site. How can I check if that really was port-problems with the StreamSocket-Code?

Comment: Do you have the control of that website. By checking the port I mean check whether the port allows for connection from your server, which is configured in your firewall rule for specific port. And how did you managed connect to the httpclient, can you share it?

Comment: interesting. It could have been firewall-rules, I never checked them before. As for connecting with httpClient, it's an other class from UWP. The Website I was trying to connect to had authentification Cookies. I think that was the real problem. with httpClient I could create a HttpRequestMessage and then add the Cookie to the message like this : req.Headers.Add("Cookie", "com.SOMECookieURL")